# Select start and end date in same calendar [JQuery]

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am making a bookingsystem, and want to have one big calendar (table), with some information in a little box to the right.

In the box I want to textfields:

- Checkin date
- Checkout date

How can I, preferably with JQuery, do it so when the user pushes one date in the big calendar, the value of that date is transfered to the "Checkin date-field" in the litte sidebox, and at the same time, disables any previous dates for the next selection. The next time the user pushes a date, the "Checkout date" gets that value.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery UI's DatePicker

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" );
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div class="demo">
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/>
    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>    
</div>
```

Comment: I read the question as wanting a fixed calendar, though, not a pop-up

Comment: I imagine you could still do that with the jQuery UI DatePicker.

Comment: I managed to write something that worked for me, I will post an answer once I am all done :)